# Error: Could not find or load main class в Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku

Сап, есть бот для тг, пишу на джаве, ясное дело со спрингом и мавеном, деплой делаю на хероку, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
2021-06-01T17:19:40.564913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-01T17:19:49.713843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java - Dserver.port=25099 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/ArtToolsBot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
2021-06-01T17:19:53.055857+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2021-06-01T17:19:53.118150+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-06-01T17:19:53.123660+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-06-01T17:19:53.308934+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.ArtToolsBotApplication
2021-06-01T17:19:53.419459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-01T17:19:53.603756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ua.sillmarry</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtToolsBot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ArtToolsBot</name>
<description>Project for ArtTools Telegram Bot</description>

<properties>

    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <telegrambots.version>5.2.0</telegrambots.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Group -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQL Group -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Telegram Bot API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>${telegrambots.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.ArtToolsBotApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.ArtToolsBotApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было вставить в `build` следующие плагины:

```
<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```